# download file and overwrite any preexisting file that has the same name - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've currently created a class (subclassing threading) I intend to use to download files from urls.  I'm also using requests if that makes a difference.  This is all working just fine, but I'd like to add some features and don't know the proper way to go about it.

Many times the file I'll download is being downloaded again (periodically) to get the latest version. So in this case I would like to:

1. Download the file with a temporary file name.
2. Overwrite the preexisting file, **only** when I'm sure a complete download of the file has taken place.
3. Delete the temporary file.

Thanks.

**Edit**: Added code I have so far...

```
import requests
import threading

class FileDownload(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, save_as_name=None, chunk_size=1024):

        # Call the constructor from the inherited class
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        # Class attributes
        self.url = url
        self.save_as_name = save_as_name
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.file_size = 0
        self.bytes_received = 0
        self.stop_download = False


    def run(self):
        self._download()


    def _download(self):
        # If no file save_as_name is provided, use the name of the file
        # from the url
        if self.save_as_name == None:
            self.save_as_name = self.url.split('/')[-1]    
        # Create a Response object
        response = requests.get(self.url, stream=True, timeout=10)
        # Get the size of the file to be downloaded in bytes
        self.file_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length'))

        with open(self.save_as_name, 'wb') as file:
            # Write downloaded file contents per iteration
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
                # Mechanism to stop download and therefore its thread
                if self.stop_download == False:
                    file.write(chunk)
                    # Keep track of the total bytes recieved per iteration
                    self.bytes_received = self.bytes_received + len(chunk)
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: You can easily create temporary files with `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` or even doing something like adding a uuid from `uuid.uuid4()` to the file name. Then its just a question of either deleting the file or renaming it when you are done.

Comment: I've added the code I have so far